Nuxt 3 server middleware touching to client pages
I'm kinda new at nuxt.
I'm trying to protect my API endpoint with authorization middleware.
(Using auth-utils with default configuration)
I'm basically returning unauthorized error code if path is not one of auth/login or /auth/register and user is not authenticated.
The issue is, instead of working only for /api/ path, it covers whole app. For example it also returns 401 when i go to http://localhost:3000/
I can add this line but it feels dirty and am missing something.
    if (!event.path.startsWith("/api")) {
        return;
    }

Is this where we handle the whole SSR or i am missing something?
/server/middleware/auth.js
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {

    const DoNotCheck = ["/auth/login", "/auth/register"];
    const { loggedIn, user } = getUserSession(event);
    if (!DoNotCheck.includes(event.path) && !loggedIn) {
        console.log("Unauthorized access attempt to", event.path);
        setResponseStatus(event, 401);
        return { error: "Unauthorized", refs: 'mw-auth' };
    }

    // Continue to next handler

});


I suppose you need to register a middleware specifically for /api with https://nuxt.com/docs/api/nuxt-config#serverhandlers
